# Convert comma separated string to 2d array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Having a bit of a brain-fail on this one. The data I need to convert are column headers for a csv file, coming to my method as:

```
['1,2,3', 'a,b,c']
```

Where 1, 2 and 3 are the first, second and third header rows, so they need to go from horizontal to vertical.

What I'm looking for as output is:

```
[['1', 'a'], ['2', 'b'], ['3', 'c']]
```

Each inner array is now a row of headers that I can loop through and add to my CSV.

I don't know before hand how many header rows there will be, but they will always be comma delimited as in the first code snippet.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`Array#transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose). It, well, transposes a matrix.

```
a = ['1,2,3', 'a,b,c'] 

a.map{|s| s.split(',')}.transpose # => [["1", "a"], ["2", "b"], ["3", "c"]]
```